# How can I use google sheets api data in discord.js embed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets-api, discord.js

I'm setting up my first discord bot, which will be able to take data from a Google Spreadsheet, from the official API and bring it as a embed message in discord. The problem is at the level of the .addField(), where I can not enter the value of the cell. How can I do this?

```
const { Client, RichEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const client= new Client();
const GoogleSpreadsheet = require('google-spreadsheet');
const {promisify} = require('util');
const creds = require('./client_secret.json');

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!bot'){

        async function accessSpreadsheet() {
            const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('1qA11t460-ceILmwu6RtfiPGb_n9MUD_7z6Ld7I_Z6yc');
            await promisify(doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(creds);
            const info = await promisify(doc.getInfo)();
            var sheet = info.worksheets[0];

            var cells = await promisify(sheet.getCells)({
                'min-row': 2,
                'max-row': 5,
                'min-col': 3,
                'max-col': 3,
                'return-empty': true,
            })
            for (var cell of cells) {
                message.author.send(cell.value)
            }
        }

        accessSpreadsheet();
        const embede = new RichEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle("My Title")
    .addBlankField()
    .setDescription('Some description')
    .addBlankField()
    .addField('Name', '•'+ cell[1].value , true)
    .setTimestamp();

        message.author.send(embede) }
})
client.login('xxx')
```

I expect the output "Terrassycup 3", but the actual output is "ReferenceError: cell is not defined" in console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues I see with your code:

- `accessSpreadsheet()` doesn't return any values it accesses.
- `accessSpreadhseet()` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) since it's declared as [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), but it's never awaited.
- The [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) of `cell` is within the `for...of` loop inside the `accessSpreadsheet()` function, yet you try to use it well outside of it.

Instead of sending each individual value to the user, you can add them as fields to the embed (the limit is 25) *within* the function you declare.

```js
async function accessSpreadsheet(embed) {
  // Insert the code already being used up to the for loop.

  for (let i = 0; i < 25 && cells[i]; i++) embed.addField('Name', `•${cells[i].value}`, true);
}

var embed = new RichEmbed()
  .setColor('#0099ff')
  .setTitle('**Spreadsheet Info**')
  .setDescription('Showing as many values as possible...');

accessSpreadsheet(embed)
  .then(() => message.author.send(embed))
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I do not understand where the "i" [for (let i = 0; i < 25 && cells[i]; i++) embed.addField('Name', `•${cells[i].value}`, true);] comes from and what does it do. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: This `for` loop uses a "step" variable (`i`). The loop will stop if the conditions `i < 25` (you can only add 25 fields to an embed) and `cells[i]` (there's a cell at that index) are **not** both true. Each time the code is executed, it adds 1 to the step to continue on through the array. `embed.addField(...)` is adding each cell's value to the given embed. `${...}` is a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)/embedded expression.

Comment: Ok, and what can I do to put "1." at the first cells[i].value, a "2." at the second, ... ?

Comment: Use `i + 1` (`i` is zero-based to match the indexes of the array), for example `${i + 1} ${cells[i].value}`